Can't create React Native app through npm
I'm trying to create a react native app using the command
npx create-expo-app@latest --template
But it keeps giving me this error
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\kurt
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\kurt'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\kurt&kobe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-19T12_57_23_204Z-debug-0.log
I reinstalled node and npm so they are up to date. I tried looking up ways on how to install expo-cli like npm i expo and npm i expo-cli -g caused the logs says deprecated, don't know if that's normal. The only thing I think could be causing the issue is the ampersand in my user's directory folder name, I might be wrong though. Hope anyone can help.

It 100% looks like an issue with the ampersand. I would consider this a bug though. Might be interesting to report it
